# Overhead of setting ClassLoader

Tags: java, performance, classloader

Is there overhead to changing the ClassLoader via:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(otherClassLoader);
```

Would it be considered bad practice change the ClassLoader before and after a method call which requires an isolated ClassLoader, for example:

```
public class CallsThingsInIsolatedClassLoader {
  // Set these references when the ClassLoaders are built
  public static ClassLoader isolatedClassLoader;
  public static ClassLoader normalClassLoader;


  public static Object getResult() {
    Object result = null;
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(isolatedClassLoader);
    result = Foo.getResult(); // Call method which requires an isolated ClassLoader.
    Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(normalClassLoader);
    return result;
  }
```

Could this cause any performance concerns? Would it be a better practice to keep something like a thread pool for calling methods which require an isolated ClassLoader, to avoid switching the ClassLoader?

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/8fe3cb32ff83/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l1501) indicates there is very little overhead in setting a different classloader for a thread. Repeated calls may cause performance concerns (the native method `currentThread()` is not free either), but it would have to be used heavily.

It is not bad practice to change the ClassLoader before and after a method call that requires it, but it is bad practice to not guarantee restoring the original ClassLoader. In other words, always use a finally clause to restore the original ClassLoader:

```
    final Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    final ClassLoader orgCl = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
    Object result = null;
    currentThread.setContextClassLoader(myCl);
    try {
        result = Foo.getResult();
    } finally {
        currentThread.setContextClassLoader(orgCl);
    }
```